# Want to create a daily "open" feature derived from : MO 00:00-23:59 TU 00:00-23:59 etc in phyton

Tags: pandas, dataframe, date, datetime

I have masterdata openings hours available to me like : MO 00:00-23:59 TU 00:00-23:59 WE 00:00-23:59 TH 00:00-23:59 FR 00:00-23:59 SA 00:00-23:59 SU 00:00-23:59

I would like to use this to create a feature for each date individually.

In order to restock a store I need to plan this event. The created feature I want to use to validate the possibility of restocking.

I have tried searching and doing stuff with split to no prevail. hopefully someone recognizes this problem?

Dataframe 1

```
store | restock_hours
store a | MO 00:00-23:59 TU 00:00-23:59 etc
store b | MO 00:00-23:59 TU 00:00-23:59 etc
store c | MO 00:00-23:59 TU 00:00-23:59 etc
```

Dataframe 2

```
store   | date       | forcast consumption | stock | open(for restock)
store a | 2019-06-11 | 1000                | 1500  | yes/no ??
store a | 2019-06-12 | 500                 | 500   | yes/no ??
store a | etc...
```

Comment: can you add a simple input & output dataframe? please see [mcve] and [ask]

Comment: @Manakin  is this more clear? .. hmm.. format got messed up.

Comment: correct: MO 00:00-23:59 TU 00:00-23:59 WE 00:00-23:59 TH 00:00-23:59 FR 00:00-23:59 SA 00:00-23:59 SU 00:00-23:59  = 1 field in a dataframe

Comment: to make it more complete so you can see how times between stores can differ: MO 08:00-20:00 TU 08:00-20:00 WE 08:00-20:00 TH 08:00-20:00 FR 08:00-20:00 SA 08:00-20:00 this is another.. note that SU is absent.

Comment: df 2 date is datetime64[ns]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is a little strange since your starting data is in a strange format, but no matter.

First step is to split out the days into rows and split out rows based on the day of the week:

```
days = (
    df1["restock_hours"]
    .str.strip()
    .str.replace("(\D{2})(\s)", r"\1_") # this adds an `_` after a a weekday name and the following space.
    .str.split(" ", expand=True)
    .stack()
    .str.split("_", expand=True)
    .rename(columns={0 : 'dayofweek'})
)

days = days.join(
    days[1].str.split("-", expand=True).rename(columns={0: "Open", 1: "Close"})
).drop(1, 1)

repl_dict = {'MO' : 'Mon','TU' : 'Tue','WE' : 'Wed'} # you can complete this. 
days['dayofweek'] = days['dayofweek'].map(repl_dict)

days['store'] = days.index.get_level_values(0).map(df1['store'])
```

---

```
print(days)

    dayofweek   Open  Close     store
0 0       Mon  00:00  23:59  store a 
  1       Tue  00:00  23:59  store a 
1 0       Mon  00:00  23:59  store b 
  1       Tue  00:00  23:59  store b 
2 0       Mon  00:00  23:59  store c 
  1       Tue  00:00  23:59  store c
```

Next we need to merge based on the day of the week - and return values in your fact dataframe.

```
pd.merge(
    df2.assign(dayofweek=df2["date"].dt.strftime("%a")),
    days,
    on=["store", "dayofweek"],
    how="left",
)

      store       date  forcast consumption  stock open(for restock)  \
0  store a  2019-06-11                 1000   1500         yes/no ??   
1  store a  2019-06-12                  500    500         yes/no ??   

  dayofweek   Open  Close  
0       Tue  00:00  23:59  
1       Wed    NaN    NaN
```

You still have a little work in regards to clean up but your requirement wasn't 100% clear so I don't want to assume.

---

## Adding a timedelta

To add a timedelta, you first need to create some date time objects. Let's do this inside a function:

```
def time_delta(input_dataframe,business_hour_start,
              business_hour_end):
    
    store_open = pd.to_datetime(input_dataframe['Open'],format='%H:%M')
    store_close = pd.to_datetime(input_dataframe['Close'],format='%H:%M')
    
    start = pd.to_datetime(business_hour_start,format='%H:%M')
    end = pd.to_datetime(business_hour_end,format='%H:%M')
    
    return start - store_open,  store_close - end

df3['start_delta'],df3['end_delta'] = time_delta(df3,'09:00','18:30')
```

[image]

Comment: Impressive! Thx it works. I'm still digesting this.. The next step hopefully you are willing to help me with, I would like to compare a x-y timeframe (I.E. standard business hours) with the open-close and add a 0 = closed during the x-y, 1 = open during x-y or 2 partly open during x-y feature to the df2. preferably x-y gotten from a df3 mo-tu-we-thu-fri-sat-sun so i can adjust later.

Comment: @yordi this is more core data modeling you need help with, I would 1. build out your fact and dimension tables/dataframes, then merge and create your calculated columns. Where are the standard business hours here?

Comment: 8:00-18:00 are the standard business hours

Comment: @yordi see edit. don't forget to accept this answer if it solved your issue(s)